# If Else Statement in Access Table Field

Tags: ms-access, if-statement

I'm super confused how to apply the if/else statement in an Access table **field**, *not* a query. Please help! Here is what I'm required to do based on the table I constructed:

5. Fill in the overall rating field, using this formula: If the is available field is false, the overall rating is “pending”, regardless of the scores.  Otherwise, if each rating score is 9 or above, the rating is ''excellent"; if the interview average is 9 or above and one rating score is less than 9, the rating is ''very good"; if the interview average is less than 9 and one (or both) rating score is 8 or above, the rating is "erratic"; otherwise the rating is "reject".

[click here to view the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al4su.jpg)

Comment: 'If the is available field is false'. Do you mean 'If the field "Available" is False"? Perhaps an Update Query would do the trick?

Comment: This looks like a practice problem, so to clarify, you do not want/cannot put an if/else statement in a table field. You would have to use a query. The practice problem is outlining the expression you should use in your query, and as @GreatCrosby stated, use an Update query to set the values in your table.

Comment: Yes, @ChristopherD is right - it's a trick question to check out if you understand database design. Create a query to do this, and cash in your _plus degree_.

Comment: A [Switch Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-Function-D750C10D-0C8E-444C-9E63-F47504F9) expression could be useful for your query.

Answer (score 2):

From Access 2010 onward you can indeed create calculated fields in a table. To do that, open the table in Design View, enter the name for the new column and choose `Calculated` as its data type.

Use the Expression Builder or any external text editor to build/write the expression for the calculated field. There is only a limited subset of functions available to be used in a calculated table field. So in this case the Expression Builder actually is helpful, as it shows only functions that can be used in this context.

To achieve the result as per your requirements, you will need an expression with several nested `Iif`-Function calls. (The `Switch` function is not available here.)
The actual expression will be same as you would use in a query.

[image: Calculated column in table design view]

This is how you can do it, if you really want to. – I agree with the commenters that in almost any case **it would be better to use a query to do any calculation of this kind**.